# How to get extension file import in odoo8?

Tags: odoo, python-import, odoo-8

I declared a variable below:

```
 

import os
......
class product(osv.osv):
      ......
      file_import = fields.Binary(string="File")
      @api.multi
      def save_file(self):
           # do something
```

If I declare variable above, can I get extension file_import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new field for storefile name and set into xml.

Example

```
----Python-----

import os
......
class product(osv.osv):
......
   file_import = fields.Binary(string="File")
   filename=fields.char('Filename')

------XML-----
<field name="filename" invisible="1"/>
<field name="file_import" filename="filename"/>
```

So, when you upload file **file_import** field it will automatically store file name into **filename** field. From filename you can get its extension.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. Can I disable or enable a button in odoo? 
Example: If <file_import> is None then button will be disable, and if <file_import> have valid then button will be enable. Thanks.

Comment: I added attribute `attrs="{'invisible':[('file_import', '=', False)]}" ` in field. But I don't like it.

Comment: yes. you can invisible from add attrs in field from xml.. instead of this i don't know how to hide field.